# Char and int16 array element both shown as 32bit hex?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, integer-promotion

In the example below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int16_t array1[] = {0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff};
    char array2[] = {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff};
    printf("Char size: %d \nint16_t size: %d \n", sizeof(char), sizeof(int16_t));

    if (*array1 == *array2)
        printf("They are the same \n");
    if (array1[0] == array2[0])
        printf("They are the same \n");

    printf("%x \n", array1[0]);
    printf("%x \n", *array1);

    printf("%x \n", array2[0]);
    printf("%x \n", *array2);
}
```

Output:

```
Char size: 1 
int16_t size: 2 
They are the same 
They are the same 
ffffffff 
ffffffff 
ffffffff 
ffffffff
```

Why are the 32bit values printed for both `char` and `int16_t` and why can they be compared and are considered the same?

Comment: The operands are being promoted to `int`s. Sign-extension of `0xff` and `0xffff` to 32 bits both yield `0xffffffff`. See sections _6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions_ and _6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers_ in [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Also, your assignments of things like `0xffff` to `int16_t`, and `0xff` to `char` if `char` is signed on your platform (it usually is) is implementation-defined. Regarding comparisons being the same, after the implementation=defined assignments are finished, you're left with *values* that are indeed the same (in your case, -1 all around).

Comment: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. So use the correct format specifier`%zu`. And `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ `1` by the standard. So you wil never get anything else.

Comment: @Michael: `char` is only sign-extended if it is signed actually. That is implementation defined (but apparently true for OP's implementation).

Comment: integral promotion is performed **because the compiler doesn't know the formal argument type** (here because it is varargs, also happens when a prototype is lacking).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're the same because they're all different representations of -1.

They print as 32 bits' worth of `ff` becaue you're on a 32-bit machine and you used `%d` and the *default argument promotions* took place (basically, everything smaller gets promoted to `int`).  Try using `%hx`.  (That'll probably get you `ffff`; I don't know of a way to get `ff` here other than by using `unsigned char`, or masking with `& 0xff`: `printf("%x \n", array2[0] & 0xff)` .)

---

Expanding on "They're the same because they're all different representations of -1":

`int16_t` is a signed 16-bit type.  It can contain values in the range -32768 to +32767.
`char` is an 8-bit type, and on your machine it's evidently signed also.  So it can contain values in the range -128 to +127.

0xff is decimal 255, a value which can't be represented in a signed char.  If you assign 0xff to a signed char, that bit pattern ends up getting interpreted not as 255, but rather as -1.  (Similarly, if you assigned 0xfe, that would be interpreted not as 254, but rather as -2.)

0xffff is decimal 65535, a value which can't be represented in an `int16_t`.  If you assign 0xffff to a `int16_t`, that bit pattern ends up getting interpreted not as 65535, but rather as -1.  (Similarly, if you assigned 0xfffe, that would be interpreted not as 65534, but rather as -2.)

So when you said

```
int16_t array1[] = {0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff};
```

it was basically just as if you'd said

```
int16_t array1[] = {-1,-1,-1,-1};
```

And when you said

```
char array2[] = {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff};
```

it was just as if you'd said

```
char array2[] = {-1,-1,-1,-1};
```

So that's why `*array1 == *array2`, and `array1[0] == array2[0]`.

---

Also, it's worth noting that all of this is very much because of the types of `array1` and `array2`.  If you instead said

```
uint16_t array3[] = {0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff};
unsigned char array4[] = {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff};
```

You would see different values printed (`ffff` and `ff`), and the values from `array3` and `array4` would not compare the same.

Another answer stated that "there is no type information in C at runtime".  That's true but misleading in this case.  When the compiler generates code to manipulate values from `array1`, `array2`, `array3`, and `array4`, the code it generates (which of course *is* significant at runtime!) will be based on their types.  In particular, when generating code to fetch values from `array1` and `array2` (but *not* `array3` and `array4`), the compiler will use instructions which perform *sign extension* when assigning to objects of larger type (e.g. 32 bits).  That's how 0xff and 0xffff got changed into 0xffffffff.

Comment: `They're the same because they're all different representations of -1.` So regardless of the type i should observe the compared values as their decimal representation?

Comment: @Alan: let me expand on that in the answer.

Comment: Use `"%hhx"` to cause the value to be cast to `unsigned char` before printing.

Comment: "So it can contain values in the range -127 to +127."  Hmmm, more likely -128 to +127.

Comment: @chux: For an 8-bit extended integral type, only -127 to +127 would be required (sign-magnitude representation is permitted).  But for `char` and `signed char`, indeed every bit pattern is required to have a distinguishable value (no -0 vs +0 issue) in order to satisfy the roundtripping requirement, so yes it should be `-128` to `+127` (if `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Comment: With exact width types, code should us matching format specifiers from `<inttypes.h>`: `printf("%" PRIx16 " \n", array1[0]);`

Comment: @chux: There's no way to pass anything smaller than `int` to `printf`, btw.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Hmmmm, On a theoretical machine with 4-byte `int` and 2-byte `char *`, what would happen with `printf("%s", "Hello")`?   Maybe a wide integer embedded processor with limited memory?  Is that case,  something smaller than `int` is passed to `printf()`.

Comment: Steve Summit @Ben point is correct that a signed `char` would have a minimal range of -127 to 127.  My point was what OP likely has.

Comment: @chux: Oh, yes, I know about 1's complement and sign/magnitude.  But when I typed "-127", it was a typo, not a deliberate acknowledgement of the other representations, because if I was acknowledging the other representations, I would have said -32767 just above.

Comment: @Steve Summit Subtle deduction: Minimum `int16_t` must be -32768 and not -32767.  Since code has `int16_t`, it _must_ be 16-bit 2's complement capable (and no padding), and _certainly_ 2's complement for `char` be it 8 or 16 bit, padded or not, signed or unsigned.  Things are more complex when code mixes base types with exact width ones - Sigh.

Comment: char cannot be padded and must have 2**CHAR_BIT unique values. No sign magnitude or ones complement allowed.

Comment: It should be clarified that the out-of-range assignment is *implementation-defined* and it's theoretically possible that some systems will store a different value than `-1`

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no type information in C *at runtime* and by using a plain `%x` for printing, you tell `printf` that your pointer points to an `unsigned int`. Poor library function just trusts you ... see **Length modifier** in [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for how to give `printf` the information it needs.

Comment: Does `no type information in C at runtime` imply that the compared elements (`(*array1 == *array2`)  are also cast to some default type before comparison?

Comment: Technically, that's not even a cast any more *at runtime* as there aren't any types, just bytes of data ;) But yes, from the compiler's view, comparing 2 integers of different sizes means converting the smaller one to the same size as the bigger one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `%x` to print negative values causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) so you should not assume that there is anything sensible about what you are seeing.

The correct format specifier for `char` is `%hhd`, and for `int16_t` it is `"%" PRId16`.  You will need `#include <inttypes.h>` to get the latter macro.

Because of the *default argument promotions*, it is also correct to use `%d` with `char` and `int16_t` <sup>1</sup>.  If you change your code to use `%d` instead of `%x`, it will no longer exhibit undefined behaviour, and the results will make sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> The C standard doesn't actually say that, but it's assumed that that was the intent of the writers.